# Rearrange a column (int) in jquery datatable while search

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to rearrange a column (int) during search in the jQuery dataTable but found no way. The following link will clearly depict the issue i have.

http://s3.postimg.org/6hwa5e637/Capture.jpg

You can see that after search the 1st column (Serial #) has numbers 2 and 3. Instead I need 1 and 2 there.

There must be a solution and I'm badly in need of it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that you want your rows to be numbered? I am not sure what you mean by "rearranged". Perhaps sharing your DataTables initialization code would shed some light on your problem?

*Don't have enough reputation to comment, but will edit this answer post if Ashik clarifies his question and I have an answer.*

**Edit:** Since you're trying to number your rows, look into using the mRender property of a column (in aoColumns). It is a function you can define for custom column rendering where you could place logic for row numbering. I'll leave the logic for that to you, but point you to some relevant material on mRender: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: Exactly jakotheshadows. I wan't the code to be numbered starting from 1.